A Poisson Process in which the rate of events increases as more event happens?
I am trying to define a (Non-Homogenous) Poisson Process such that the rate of events increases as the cumulative number of events increases.
I tried to do this as follows:
First, I defined a rate function that reflects this behavior (i.e. rate of events increases as the number of arrivals increases.)
$$\lambda(t) = \lambda_0 \cdot e^{\alpha N(t)}$$
Where:

$λ(t)$ is the rate function at time $t$
$λ₀$ is the base rate
$α$ is a positive constant that controls how quickly the rate increases
$N(t)$ is the number of events that have already happened by time $t$

Using this rate function, I tried to write a Poisson Process:
$$P(N(t+h) - N(t) = k) = \frac{(\int_t^{t+h} \lambda(s)ds)^k}{k!} e^{-\int_t^{t+h} \lambda(s)ds} + o(h)$$
Finally, I wanted to prove that this process has accelerating departures. I thought we could demonstrate this by showing that the time between successive departures tends to decrease.
Define  $T₁$ be the time until the first departure and $T₂$ be the time between the first and second departures. We need to show that $P(T₂ < t) > P(T₁ < t)$ for any given $t$, which would indicate that $T₂$ is likely to be smaller than $T₁$.
For a non-homogeneous Poisson process, the probability that the waiting time T is less than t is given by:
$$P(T < t) = 1 - e^{-\int_0^t \lambda(s)ds}$$
For $T₁$:
$$P(T_1 < t) = 1 - e^{-\int_0^t \lambda_0 \cdot e^{\alpha \cdot 0}ds} = 1 - e^{-\lambda_0 t}$$
For $T₂$, given that one person has already left:
$$P(T_2 < t) = 1 - e^{-\int_0^t \lambda_0 \cdot e^{\alpha \cdot 1}ds} = 1 - e^{-\lambda_0 e^\alpha t}$$
Now, let's compare these probabilities:
$$P(T_2 < t) - P(T_1 < t) = (1 - e^{-\lambda_0 e^\alpha t}) - (1 - e^{-\lambda_0 t}) = e^{-\lambda_0 t} - e^{-\lambda_0 e^\alpha t}$$
Since $α > 0$, we know that $e^α > 1$, which means $λ₀e^α > λ₀$. Therefore:
$$e^{-\lambda_0 t} > e^{-\lambda_0 e^\alpha t}$$
This implies:
$$P(T_2 < t) - P(T_1 < t) > 0$$
Thus, for any given $t$, $P(T₂ < t) > P(T₁ < t)$, which means $T₂$ is more likely to be smaller than $T₁$. This mathematically demonstrates the accelerated departure condition.
Intuitively, this means that after the first person leaves, the probability of the next departure happening within any given time frame increases. As more people leave, this effect compounds, leading to increasingly rapid departures.
This acceleration becomes even more pronounced as more people leave. For the kth departure, the probability would be:
$$P(T_k < t) = 1 - e^{-\lambda_0 e^{\alpha(k-1)} t}$$
As k increases, the exponent grows exponentially, making the probability of a quick next departure increasingly high.
Does my work make sense?


Supporting Proof 1: Here, I tried to show why the probability that the waiting time $T$ is less than $t$ for a non-homogeneous Poisson process is given by:
$$P(T < t) = 1 - e^{-\int_0^t \lambda(s)ds}$$
Consider the complementary event:
$$P(T \geq t) = 1 - P(T < t)$$
$P(T ≥ t)$ represents the probability that no events occur before time $t$.
In a non-homogeneous Poisson process, the number of events $N(t)$ in an interval [0, t] follows a Poisson distribution with mean:
$$\mu(t) = \int_0^t \lambda(s)ds$$
The probability of no events occurring ($k = 0$) in a Poisson distribution is given by:
$$P(N(t) = 0) = \frac{e^{-\mu(t)} \cdot \mu(t)^0}{0!} = e^{-\mu(t)}$$
Substituting $μ(t)$:
$$P(T \geq t) = P(N(t) = 0) = e^{-\int_0^t \lambda(s)ds}$$
Now, we derive our original formula:
$$P(T < t) = 1 - P(T \geq t) = 1 - e^{-\int_0^t \lambda(s)ds}$$

Supporting Proof 2: Here, I tried to show the expected number of events between two time periods.
The formula for the expected number of departures in the interval (t, t+h) is:
$$E[N(t+h) - N(t)] = \int_t^{t+h} \lambda(s)ds$$
If we can divide the interval ($t$, $t+h$) into $n$ very small subintervals, each of length $Δt = h/n$. As $n$ approaches infinity, $Δt$ approaches zero.
In each small subinterval, we can approximate the process as a homogeneous Poisson process with rate $λ(s_i)$, where $s_i$ is some point in the $i^{th}$ subinterval.
The expected number of events in each small subinterval is approximately $λ(s_i) * Δt$. This is from basic logic, i.e. multiply the rate of events by the time period in which events can happen.
Summing over all these small subintervals, we get:
$$E[N(t+h) - N(t)] \approx \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda(s_i) \cdot \Delta t$$
As $n$ approaches infinity (and $Δt$ approaches zero), this sum approaches the integral:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda(s_i) \cdot \Delta t = \int_t^{t+h} \lambda(s)ds$$

thank you for your feedback... but does the non-homogenous poisson process still need to obey independent increments?

thank you again ... just to clarify : a non homogenous poisson process DOES follow the independent increment property ?

thank you Michael ... I created a math puzzle ... I am soon going to post it and the work I have done it ...it relates to this question ... I hope you will like it :)

I have deleted the above comments (which had confusing typos) and have instead summarized them in an answer below.

I think this is a type of Hawkes process: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawkes_process

@Ziv: Thank you... Do you think the process I wrote above can be re-written as a Hawkes process?

This is not really an inhomogeneous Poisson process because independence of increments fails. An inhomogeneous Poisson process has $\lambda(t)$ that is a given (nonrandom) function of time, such as $\lambda(t)=5+\cos(t)$ for all $t\geq 0$. The independent increments property can fail if we allow $\lambda(t)$ to depend on the number of arrivals before time $t$.
You really have a system with arrivals that occur according to mutually independent inter-arrival times $\{X_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$, where $X_k \sim Exp(\lambda_0e^{\alpha (k-1)})$ for $k \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.  The expected time to reach the $k$th arrival is
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^kE[X_i] &= \sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{\lambda_0e^{\alpha(i-1)}} \\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda_0e^{\alpha(i-1)}}\\ &=\frac{e^{\alpha}}{\lambda_0(e^{\alpha}-1)} \quad \forall k \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}
\end{align}
This means $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} E[X_i]$, which can be viewed as the expected time to get an "infinite" number of arrivals, is actually finite. This is unusual and it means there is a positive probability of getting an infinite number of arrivals in finite time. Indeed, if we let $T=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}X_i$ then $E[T]$ is finite
$$ E[T] = \frac{e^{\alpha}}{\lambda_0(e^{\alpha}-1)}$$
and by the Markov inequality we get
$$P[T\geq 2E[T]] \leq \frac{1}{2}$$
which means
$$P[T<2E[T]]\geq 1/2$$
So with probability at least $1/2$, we get an infinite number of arrivals before time $2E[T]$.
It also means that we cannot define $N(t)$ as an integer process as usual because $N(t)\rightarrow \infty$ in finite time, so $N(t)=\infty$ if $t\geq T$.

Thank you for the answer! to clarify, the process I wrote is a valid stochastic process , but it is NOT a Poisson Process (Homogenous or Non Homogenous) since it DOES NOT respect the independent increments property?

@heartofdarkness it does not and does not need to have independent increments. It is either a Hawkes or a Cox process. So that territory of naming if after someone looks preþy much claimed.

@ Michael: How would we prove that the process I defined in my question is not a poisson process? can this be done using first principles? Is it possible to show that my process is not memoryless?
